# Как программно зажать кнопку на n секунд

Tags: android, button

Нужно чтобы пользователю отображалось зажатие кнопки на определенное время, после чего возвращалась в исходное положение. Будто эта кнопка держалась пальцем все это время, но чтобы это делала программа

Comment: у кнопки есть такой метод - setEnabled(). ставите его в true, отсчитываете время, ставите в false

Comment: Хотелось бы именно нажатие. Возможно?

Comment: если нужно именно событие клика, а не только визуальное отображение, то тогда есть метод performClick()

Answer (score 0):

На кнопку можно навесить `drawable` с background для разных состояний. Для нормального одно, для нажатого другое. Можно просто сделать поменять эти background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_normal" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_pressed" />
</selector>
```